# Can I make an ethereum token that runs a certain function every 15 seconds?

Tags: ether, mining, testnets, rinkeby

I have a rinkeby token, and I wanted to add "merged mining" when someone mines a block, they get awarded 0.25 of that token.

```
function issueBlockReward() {
balanceOf[block.coinbase] += 0.25;
```

The code above (I am missing the bottom closing tag)
Awards the miner of an ethereum block 0.25 token.
How can I make this run every 15 seconds?
My pragma version is v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You basically already did it.  As long as block reward will worth it, miners will include invocation of your function into every block they mine.

However, I see minor problem with your code.  As long as all token balances and transfer amounts have to be integer, your block reward has to be integer as well.

Comment: Thanks! I have a slight problem though. It is returning an error! `No matching declaration found after variable lookup.
balanceOf[block.coinbase] += 1;`

Comment: Could you show the whole smart contract?

Comment: Nvm, I fixed that.
How would a miner include it into the function